# Filter a CSV file that has text above column names that must be maintained after the filter process

Tags: r, csv, filter

I work with hundreds of CSV files that have three lines of text above multiple column headers.

[image: CSV example].

These files can be as large as 300MB. They need to be filtered down to < 1/3 the size in local preprocessing, before the result is pushed to a server for processing. Filtering is fine when the three lines are removed on upload.

```
A <- read_csv_arrow( p , as_data_frame = TRUE, skip = 3)
```

But the problem is replacing the text (the first three lines) in the same state post filtering, as that information is relevant in a later processing.

I have tried multiple approaches isolating the text as an object then using cat() to replace it after filtering, but the process must end with a CSV, which I have been unsuccessful achieving.

Answer (score 2):

The following does not use `read_csv_arrow`, it uses `readLines/read.csv` to read in the file. This is meant to return a **named list** object with two members:

1. `header` are the first 3 lines;
2. `data` is the table that follows the first 3 lines.

Then, function `write_special` will write a list with those members.

### File `"so_test.csv"` content:

```
Text 1st line
Text 2nd line
Text 3rd line
a,b,c
1,5,9
2,6,10
3,7,11
4,8,12
```

### Code

In `read_special` you can replace `read.csv` by `read_csv_arrow` but the return value must be a list with those named members. The header can be read with `readLines`, then skip the first 3 lines before reading the table.

Pass that list after pre-processing the table and write the list back to disk with `write_special`.

```
read_special <- function(file, n = 3L, skip = n, ...) {
  x <- readLines(file, n = n)
  y <- read.csv(file, skip = skip, ...)
  list(header = x, data = y)
}

write_special <- function(x, file, ...) {
  writeLines(text = x$header, con = file)
  write.table(x$data, file = file, sep = ",", append = TRUE, ...)
}

path <- "~/Temp"
infile <- file.path(path, "so_test.csv")
outfile <- file.path(path, "so_test_2.csv")

x <- read_special(infile)
x
# $header
# [1] "Text 1st line" "Text 2nd line" "Text 3rd line"
#
# $data
#   a b  c
# 1 1 5  9
# 2 2 6 10
# 3 3 7 11
# 4 4 8 12

write_special(x, file = outfile, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
Warning message:  
In write.table(x$data, file = file, sep = ",", append = TRUE, ...) :  
  appending column names to file
```

### File `"so_test_2.csv"` content:

The output file is identical to the input file.

```
Text 1st line
Text 2nd line
Text 3rd line
a,b,c
1,5,9
2,6,10
3,7,11
4,8,12
```

Comment: Rui thank you for your response. I had no idea of the existence of read_special. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JWeber `read_special` is a function I just made up. It doesn't exist in a package, only here. And, more importantly, glad to help.

Comment: Meant readLines.Thx

Answer (score 1):

Use `write.table`, twice.

Suppose you have stored the first three lines into an object called `text`.
Write that to a csv file with no row or column headers:

```
write.table(text, file="filename.csv", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Then append the filtered data frame called, say `mydata`, to this csv file.

```
write.table(mydata, file="filename.csv", sep=",", append=TRUE)
```

Comment: You can also use `fwrite` from the data.table package if performace is an issue.